# Haskell type synonym issue

Tags: haskell, pattern-synonyms

This gives me the following error

> Not in scope: data constructor `Blah`

Why? I thought that I can use the type synonym everywhere I can use `Person`

```
data Person = Person { weight :: Int, height :: Int }

type Blah = Person

person1 :: Blah
person1 = Blah 80 187
```

Comment: `Blah` is an alias for the `Person` type, not the `Person` constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You've aliased the type `Person` to the name `Blah`, but the constructor for `Person` is still `Person {weight :: Int, height :: Int}`.  Type constructors and Type names are different and are even kept in different namespaces in Haskell.

As an example:

```
> data MyBool = MyFalse | MyTrue deriving (Show, Eq)
> type Blah = MyBool
```

Here the constructors for `MyBool` are `MyFalse` and `MyTrue`, each with kind `*` (no type parameters).  I then alias `MyBool` to `Blah`:

```
> MyTrue :: MyBool
MyTrue
> MyTrue :: Blah
MyTrue
```

This should help enforce the idea that while a type's constructor might share the same name as the type itself, they are not the same things.

Answer (score 2):

In the hottest GHC 7.8 you could write in such manner:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

data Person = Person { weight :: Int, height :: Int }

type Bar = Person     -- type synonym
pattern Baz = Person  -- constructor synonym


person1 :: Bar
person1 = Baz 80 187
```

But sure, don't forget `Person` is a type and `Person` ia a constructor and both are in different scope.